# php - compare years with different data types

Tags: php, string, int, comparison, laravel-5.1

I found that `?year=2015` works on my website, the same way, `?year=2015sjkhdkfzgsfkzgsk` does, when this 'year' is compared to the integer value from the database (MySQL YEAR type), somehow like this:

```
$year = Input::get('year');
$dbyear = Pic::find($id)->value('year');
if($year == $dbyear){
    //..
}
```

because this seems to return true:

```
var_dump(2015 == '2015abcdefg34748fhhdfgxfgfg');
```

Is this normal or possibly a bug? How can I better compare these values? Now I am doing:

```
$year = substr(Input::get('year'),0,4);
```

Comment: It's [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion): *"The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. "*  (via [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could force the argument to `string` data type:

```
 $year = strval(Input::get('year'));
```